# How do I make a camera that points towards where the player is going and is back and up and pointed down?

Tags: unity-game-engine

it is a ball that actally rolls so I can't just put a child camera on with an offset and call it a day so instead I created this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class camera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player;
    public Vector3 lastpos;
    public Vector3 cameraxyz;
    public Vector3 camerarotationxyz;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 currentDirection = Player.transform.position - lastpos;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(currentDirection-camerarotationxyz);
        transform.position = currentDirection + cameraxyz;
        Vector3 lastPos = Player.transform.position;
    }
}
```

and attached it to an empty game object made the game object a child of the ball and then made the camera a child of the empty game object

which half works the empty game object will all always rotate to have it's z axis aligned with the origin meaning the offset for the camera is wrong and it won't look at where the ball is going but will look towards the ball

this is how I set the hierarchy up (I put the script on the empty game object)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbiMt.png

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class camera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player;
    public Vector3 lastPos;
    public Vector3 cameraxyz;
    public Vector3 camerarotationxyz;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 currentDirection = Player.transform.position - lastPos;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(currentDirection - new Vector3(0,currentDirection.y,0));
        Vector3 newPosition = currentDirection + cameraxyz;
        transform.position = newPosition;
        lastPos = Player.transform.position;
        transform.position = Player.transform.position;
    }
}
```

taking the Vector3 off of lastPos and capitalizing mistakes leads to a gameobject with an incorrect offset and rotation to stop it traking the y axis (as I can change which whay is up and change the y to be parrallel to gravity using an external script) I did `(currentDirection - new Vector3(0,currentDirection.y,0)` the new Vector3 is needed and so are the zeros as a float nor int cannot be use to subtract from a Vector3 then I did `transform.position = Player.transform.position;` so that the empty game object is correctly put on the ball then to get the camera to move with the correct offset I made the camera a child of the emptygameobject